# Safari Jumping Between Inputs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, safari

I'm trying to create a login page with two customized, controlled inputs inside a form for the user's Email and Password. As soon as I start typing in the password input, the cursor jumps back and continues typing in the email input. This only happens on safari. Why is this happening and how can I prevent this from happening?

Here's the Login page:

```
const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const email = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.loginSlice.email)
  const password = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.loginSlice.password)

  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState<boolean>(false);  

  const handleChange = (e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, type: string) => {
    if (loginError) setLoginError(false)
    if (type === "password") dispatch(setPassword(e.target.value))
    else if (type === "email") dispatch(setEmail(e.target.value))
  }

  const handleBackButton = () => {
    navigate('/intro')
    dispatch(resetEmailAndPassword())
  }

  return (
    <div id='login_page' data-theme={darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light'} style={{display: loginPage === LoginNav.MainLogin ? "flex": "none"}}>
      <div id='login_content'>
        <button id="back_button" onClick={handleBackButton}>
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fillRule="evenodd" clipRule="evenodd" d="M9.90906 7.26521C9.50324 6.8906 8.87058 6.9159 8.49597 7.32172L5.2652 10.8217C4.9116 11.2047 4.9116 11.7952 5.26519 12.1782L8.49597 15.6783C8.87057 16.0841 9.50323 16.1094 9.90905 15.7348C10.3149 15.3602 10.3402 14.7276 9.96558 14.3217L8.28397 12.5L18 12.5C18.5523 12.5 19 12.0523 19 11.5C19 10.9477 18.5523 10.5 18 10.5L8.284 10.5L9.96557 8.67829C10.3402 8.27247 10.3149 7.63981 9.90906 7.26521Z" fill="var(--textBody)"/>
            </svg>
        </button>
        <h1>Hi, Welcome Back!</h1>
        <h2>Sign in to your account</h2>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => handleLogin(e)} id="login_form">
          <CustomTextInput
            key={1}
            id="login_email_input"
            type='email'
            placeholder='Email'
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "email")}
            value={email}
            autocomplete='username'
            keyHint='next'
            error={loginError}
          />
          <CustomTextInput
            key={2}
            id="login_password_input"
            type='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "password")}
            value={password}
            autocomplete='current-password'
            keyHint='done'
            error={loginError}
          />
          <a onClick={() => navigate('/reset')} id='forgot_link'>Forgot Password?</a>
          <CustomButton text='Login' value="Submit"/>
        </form>
        <span>Don't have an account? <Link onClick={() => dispatch(resetEmailAndPassword())} to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The Custom Text input component:

```
type keyHintType = 'enter' | 'search' | 'done' | 'go' | 'next' | 'previous' | 'send' | undefined

interface CopyButtonProps {
  value: string|number
  readonly?: boolean
}

const CustomTextInput: React.FunctionComponent<{
  onChange?: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>
  value: string | number
  type?: string
  placeholder?: string
  readonly?: boolean
  id?: string
  error?: boolean
  disabled?: boolean
  autocomplete?: string
  keyHint?: keyHintType
}> = ({ id, onChange, value, placeholder, type = 'text', error = false, disabled = false, autocomplete, readonly = false, keyHint = 'enter'}) => {

  const darkMode = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.settingsSlice.darkMode)

  const handleLabelStyle = (): {display: 'flex'}|undefined => {
    if (type === 'text' || type === 'password' || type === 'email') {
      if (typeof value === 'string' && value.length > 0) {
        return {
          display: 'flex'
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const EmailIcon: React.FC<{darkMode:boolean}> = ({darkMode}) => {
    if (darkMode) return (
      <svg id='email_icon' width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style={placeholder?.includes('Email') ? { display: 'flex' } : { display: 'none' }}>
        <path d="M5.01107 3.33154C3.17024 3.33154 1.67773 4.82404 1.67773 6.66487V13.3315C1.67773 15.1724 3.17024 16.6649 5.01107 16.6649H15.0111C16.8519 16.6649 18.3444 15.1724 18.3444 13.3315V6.66487C18.3444 4.82404 16.8519 3.33154 15.0111 3.33154H5.01107ZM5.01107 4.99821H15.0111C15.8511 4.99821 16.5453 5.61488 16.6603 6.42321C15.8619 7.16738 14.6753 8.08071 13.8911 8.64404C12.0869 9.93987 10.4994 10.8315 10.0111 10.8315C9.52275 10.8315 7.93524 9.9407 6.13107 8.64404C5.3469 8.08071 4.57608 7.47154 3.99524 6.97737C3.74774 6.76654 3.5644 6.59654 3.42273 6.45654C3.53773 5.64821 4.17107 4.99821 5.01107 4.99821ZM3.35275 8.62654C5.46775 10.3374 8.56691 12.4882 10.0111 12.4982C10.9519 12.5049 12.5611 11.6065 14.2028 10.4724C15.0519 9.88487 15.9969 9.18737 16.6786 8.61487L16.6778 13.3315C16.6778 14.2524 15.9319 14.9982 15.0111 14.9982H5.01107C4.09024 14.9982 3.3444 14.2524 3.3444 13.3315L3.35275 8.62654Z" fill={error? "#F2F6E": "#797D9D"}/>
      </svg>
    )
    else return (
      <svg
        id='email_icon'
        width='20'
        height='20'
        viewBox='0 0 20 20'
        fill='none'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        style={placeholder?.includes('Email') ? { display: 'flex' } : { display: 'none' }}
      >
        <path style={error ? { fill: '#EF2F6E' } : { fill: '#98A0A0' }} d='M4.96037 3.33154C3.26537 3.33154 1.93872 3.75987 1.70455 5.38904C1.62955 5.9107 1.79454 6.42405 2.17371 6.79488C2.36204 6.97904 2.56121 7.19821 2.82455 7.41988C3.48538 7.97738 4.32788 8.60404 5.11622 9.16487C7.28539 10.7065 8.99789 11.6649 10.0121 11.6649C11.0262 11.6649 12.7387 10.7065 14.9079 9.16487C15.6971 8.60404 16.5396 7.97654 17.1996 7.41988C17.4629 7.19821 17.6621 6.97988 17.8504 6.79488C18.2296 6.42405 18.3946 5.9107 18.3196 5.38904C18.0854 3.75987 16.7587 3.33154 15.0637 3.33154H4.96037ZM1.67871 8.46154V13.3315C1.67871 15.1724 3.17121 16.6649 5.01205 16.6649H15.0121C16.8529 16.6649 18.3454 15.1724 18.3454 13.3315V8.46154C17.6621 9.11071 16.8987 9.78071 15.8196 10.5449C13.4562 12.2182 11.3337 13.3315 10.0121 13.3315C8.69039 13.3315 6.56789 12.2182 4.20455 10.5449C3.12455 9.78071 2.36205 9.11071 1.67871 8.46154Z' fill='#98A0A0' />
      </svg>
    )
  }

  const PasswordIcon: React.FC<{darkMode:boolean}> = ({darkMode}) => {
    if (darkMode) return (
      <svg id='password_icon' width="14" height="18" viewBox="0 0 14 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style={type === 'password' ? { display: 'flex' } : { display: 'none' }}>
        <path d="M6.9987 0.627441C4.69786 0.627441 2.83203 2.49327 2.83203 4.79411V6.46077C1.4512 6.46077 0.332031 7.57994 0.332031 8.96078V14.7941C0.332031 16.1749 1.4512 17.2941 2.83203 17.2941H11.1654C12.5462 17.2941 13.6654 16.1749 13.6654 14.7941V8.96078C13.6654 7.57994 12.5462 6.46077 11.1654 6.46077V4.79411C11.1654 2.49327 9.29953 0.627441 6.9987 0.627441ZM6.9987 2.29411C8.37953 2.29411 9.4987 3.41328 9.4987 4.79411V6.46077H4.4987V4.79411C4.4987 3.41328 5.61786 2.29411 6.9987 2.29411ZM2.83203 8.12744H3.66536H10.332H11.1654C11.6254 8.12744 11.9987 8.50078 11.9987 8.96078V14.7941C11.9987 15.2541 11.6254 15.6274 11.1654 15.6274H2.83203C2.37203 15.6274 1.9987 15.2541 1.9987 14.7941V8.96078C1.9987 8.50078 2.37203 8.12744 2.83203 8.12744ZM6.9987 8.96078C5.61786 8.96078 4.4987 10.0799 4.4987 11.4608V12.2941C4.4987 13.6749 5.61786 14.7941 6.9987 14.7941C8.37953 14.7941 9.4987 13.6749 9.4987 12.2941V11.4608C9.4987 10.0799 8.37953 8.96078 6.9987 8.96078ZM6.9987 10.6274C7.4587 10.6274 7.83203 11.0008 7.83203 11.4608V12.2941C7.83203 12.7541 7.4587 13.1274 6.9987 13.1274C6.5387 13.1274 6.16536 12.7541 6.16536 12.2941V11.4608C6.16536 11.0008 6.5387 10.6274 6.9987 10.6274Z" fill={error? "#F2F6E": "#797D9D"}/>
      </svg>
    )
    else return (
      <svg
        id='password_icon'
        width='20'
        height='20'
        viewBox='0 0 20 20'
        fill='none'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        style={type === 'password' ? { display: 'flex' } : { display: 'none' }}
      >
        <path style={error ? { fill: '#EF2F6E' } : { fill: '#98A0A0' }} d='M9.99772 1.62744C7.69689 1.62744 5.83105 3.49327 5.83105 5.79411V7.46078C4.45022 7.46078 3.33105 8.57994 3.33105 9.96078V15.7941C3.33105 17.1749 4.45022 18.2941 5.83105 18.2941H14.1644C15.5452 18.2941 16.6644 17.1749 16.6644 15.7941V9.96078C16.6644 8.57994 15.5452 7.46078 14.1644 7.46078V5.79411C14.1644 3.49327 12.2986 1.62744 9.99772 1.62744ZM9.99772 3.29411C11.3786 3.29411 12.4977 4.41327 12.4977 5.79411V7.46078H7.49772V5.79411C7.49772 4.41327 8.61689 3.29411 9.99772 3.29411ZM9.99772 9.96078C10.9186 9.96078 11.6644 10.7066 11.6644 11.6274C11.6644 12.2191 11.2952 12.6341 10.8311 12.9291V14.9608C10.8311 15.4208 10.4577 15.7941 9.99772 15.7941C9.53772 15.7941 9.16439 15.4208 9.16439 14.9608V12.9291C8.70022 12.6333 8.33105 12.2191 8.33105 11.6274C8.33105 10.7066 9.07689 9.96078 9.99772 9.96078Z' fill='#98A0A0' />
      </svg>
    )
  }

  const ExclamationPoint: React.FC = () => {
    return (
      <svg
        id='exclamation_point'
        width='20'
        height='20'
        viewBox='0 0 20 20'
        fill='none'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        style={error ? { display: 'flex' } : { display: 'none' }}
      >
        <path d='M17.5 10C17.5 11.9891 16.7098 13.8968 15.3033 15.3033C13.8968 16.7098 11.9891 17.5 10 17.5C8.01088 17.5 6.10322 16.7098 4.6967 15.3033C3.29018 13.8968 2.5 11.9891 2.5 10C2.5 8.01088 3.29018 6.10322 4.6967 4.6967C6.10322 3.29018 8.01088 2.5 10 2.5C11.9891 2.5 13.8968 3.29018 15.3033 4.6967C16.7098 6.10322 17.5 8.01088 17.5 10ZM11.0607 15.0607C11.342 14.7794 11.5 14.3978 11.5 14C11.5 13.6022 11.342 13.2206 11.0607 12.9393C10.7794 12.658 10.3978 12.5 10 12.5C9.60218 12.5 9.22064 12.658 8.93934 12.9393C8.65804 13.2206 8.5 13.6022 8.5 14C8.5 14.3978 8.65804 14.7794 8.93934 15.0607C9.22064 15.342 9.60218 15.5 10 15.5C10.3978 15.5 10.7794 15.342 11.0607 15.0607ZM10 4.5C9.60218 4.5 9.22064 4.65804 8.93934 4.93934C8.65804 5.22064 8.5 5.60217 8.5 6V10C8.5 10.3978 8.65804 10.7794 8.93934 11.0607C9.22064 11.342 9.60218 11.5 10 11.5C10.3978 11.5 10.7794 11.342 11.0607 11.0607C11.342 10.7794 11.5 10.3978 11.5 10V6C11.5 5.60217 11.342 5.22064 11.0607 4.93934C10.7794 4.65804 10.3978 4.5 10 4.5Z' fill='#ED6036' stroke='#ED6036' />
      </svg>
    )
  }

  const CopyButton = ({ value, readonly }: CopyButtonProps) => {
    return (
      <button
        id='copy_button'
        style={readonly ? { display: 'flex' } : { display: 'none' }}
        onClick={() => { navigator.clipboard.writeText(value.toString()) }}
      >
        <CopyIcon darkMode={darkMode}/>
      </button>
    )
  }

  const SearchIcon = () => {
    return (
      <svg id="search_input_icon" style={type==='search' ? {display: 'flex'}: {display: 'none'}} width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fillRule="evenodd" clipRule="evenodd" d="M12.4188 13.6002C11.2899 14.4778 9.87132 15.0003 8.33073 15.0003C4.64883 15.0003 1.66406 12.0156 1.66406 8.33366C1.66406 4.65176 4.64883 1.66699 8.33073 1.66699C12.0126 1.66699 14.9974 4.65176 14.9974 8.33366C14.9974 9.87425 14.4748 11.2928 13.5973 12.4217L18.0867 16.9111C18.4121 17.2365 18.4121 17.7641 18.0867 18.0896C17.7612 18.415 17.2336 18.415 16.9081 18.0896L12.4188 13.6002ZM13.3307 8.33366C13.3307 11.0951 11.0922 13.3337 8.33073 13.3337C5.56931 13.3337 3.33073 11.0951 3.33073 8.33366C3.33073 5.57224 5.56931 3.33366 8.33073 3.33366C11.0922 3.33366 13.3307 5.57224 13.3307 8.33366Z" fill="#63C8D0"/>
      </svg>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div id='input_group'>
      <input
        id={id}
        className={error ? 'custom_txt_input_error' : 'custom_txt_input'}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        type={type}
        disabled={disabled}
        autoComplete={autocomplete}
        style={type === 'password' || type === 'email' || type==='search' ? { paddingLeft: '2.5rem' } : { paddingLeft: '1rem' }}
        enterKeyHint={keyHint}
      />
      {placeholder
        ? <label id={error ? 'input_label_error' : 'input_label'} style={handleLabelStyle()}>{placeholder}</label>
        : null}
      <ExclamationPoint />
      <EmailIcon darkMode={darkMode}/>
      <PasswordIcon darkMode={darkMode}/>
      <SearchIcon />
      <CopyButton value={value} readonly={readonly} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And the css for the custom input component:

```
#input_group {
    margin: 0 auto 1rem auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#input_label, #input_label_error {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    line-height: 1.125rem;
    color: var(--textCaption);
    width: fit-content;
    top: -0.5rem;
    left: 1.25rem;
    background-color: var(--checkBoxBackground)
}

#input_label {
    color: var(--textCaption);
    padding:0 0.1875rem;
}

#input_label_error {
    color: var(--customRed);
}

.custom_txt_input:focus + #input_label {
    display: flex;
}

.custom_txt_input, .custom_txt_input_error {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 140%;
    /* padding: 1rem; */
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
}

.custom_txt_input:focus, .custom_txt_input_error:focus {
    overflow:hidden
}

.custom_txt_input {
    /* border: 0.125rem solid #F5F6F9; */
    border: none;
    background: var(--secondaryBackground);
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 0.125rem solid transparent;
    -webkit-user-select: inherit;
}

.custom_txt_input_error {
    border: 0.125rem solid var(--customRed);
    background-color: var(--primaryBackground);
    color: var(--textTitle);
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem 1rem 1rem;
}

.custom_txt_input:focus {
    background-color: var(--primaryBackground);
    border: 0.125rem solid var(--customBlue);
    color: var(--textTitle);
    font-weight: 400;
}

.custom_txt_input {
    color: var(--textBody);
    font-weight: 400;
}

.custom_txt_input::placeholder {
    color: var(--textCaption);
    font-weight: 400;
}

.custom_txt_input:focus::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

#create_folder_btn {
    margin: 1.625rem auto 2.25rem auto;
}

#exclamation_point {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
}

#email_icon, #password_icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
}

#copy_button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}

#search_input_icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 1rem;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Comment: I noticed this has something to do with the form. I removed the form tag and the inputs work correctly. But I need to find a way for the inputs to work with the form.

Comment: If you found the reason for this, please post your solution here.